# Can the wall reflect infrared?

Tags: reflection, infrared-radiation

One day, I was sitting in my room and the fan in front of me was on. I was holding the control of the fan in my hand and facing the wall, I pressed its switch, and contrary to what I expected, the fan that was facing the same wall turned on, and I was asked whether The wall reflects the infrared and the fan can receive it and execute the command?!

Comment: completely unclear. what did you expect?

Comment: Your wall reflects visible light. Why would light with a wavelength just slightly longer than visible light no longer reflect?

Comment: Short answer: yes it reflects infrared light.

Comment: @JonCuster, Specious argument. Why would green light not reflect off a wall that is painted with ultramarine blue? The wavelength of the green light is just slightly longer than the blue wavelengths that the paint reflects.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - I bet the ultramarine blue wall will still reflect enough green LED light to trigger a receiver just fine. Sure, high quality optical materials can do some weird things, but gloss paint on a wall seems unlikely to not reflect any near IR (as it clearly did just fine).

Comment: A lot of tv controllers generate infra red signals which are fairly directional.  Pointing the controller at different parts of a room should show that infra red can be reflected from walls and other objects.